# How to type in these "circle" and "square"?

Tags: symbols, amssymb

I am looking for an easy way to type in the square and the circle shown below:
[image]

The circles are meant for operations like +,-,>,< or `\neq` or `\geq,leq` ect. So the circles should be `small`. But the squares should be big, because they are meant for the `numbers`.

I hope to have an easy way to implement them, with auto change of size when the font size changes.

I have been looking for packages that have squares and circles, but either the square are too small, or the circles are not big enough. Also I have not found a single package that can have the two shapes.

Thanks,

Chen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}
\def\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\circ}{j}}}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}
\begin{document}
$47 + 5 \mcirc 54$

$47 + \msquare < 54$
\end{document}
```

[image]

...or, for a thinner circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}
\def\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigcirc}{t}}}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}
\begin{document}
$47 + 5 \mcirc 54$

$47 + \msquare < 54$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

The OP asks about making the box "even bigger."  Below, I show how to do that both vertically and horizontally.  Vertically, I replace the `gX` in the `\msquare` definition with `\strut`, so that the `\Box` is scaled to the same vertical extent as a `\strut`.  For horizontal expansion, one can use a asymmetric `\scalebox` to accomplish that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb,graphicx}
\def\mcirc{\mathbin{\scalerel*{\bigcirc}{t}}}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalebox{1.5}[1]{\scalerel*{\Box}{\strut}}}}
\begin{document}
$47 + 5 \mcirc 54$

$47 + \msquare < 54$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have been reading the document page. But I still dont understand what does the `t` and `gX` do here and how could I make the square even bigger?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu The `t` and `gX` are merely objects that span a certain vertical distance.  The circle is scaled to the same vertical extent as a `t` and the box is scaled to the same vertical extent as `gX`.  If you want the box bigger, you could replace `gx` with `\strut` and the box would scale to the vertical size of a `\strut`.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu See **follow up**.

Answer (score 8):

How about using `\bigcirc` for the math relations, and a regular `\fbox{$\phantom{..}$}` for the numbers. The latter will size with the numbers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.5\fboxsep}
\newcommand{\mrel}{\mathrel{\bigcirc}}% Some math relation

\begin{document}

$47 + 5 < 54$

$47 + 5 \mrel 54$

$47 + \fbox{$\phantom{5}$} < 54$

$\num{1234} + \num{56789} = \num{58023}$

$\num{1234} + \fbox{$\phantom{\num{56789}}$} = \num{58023}$

\end{document}
```