# How get \Box like symbol with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, symbols, math-fonts, tex-gyre-math

The source below, when processed with `pdflatex` produces the math symbol shown here:

[image: Unit square symbol]

But if I process the source with `xelatex`, I get error:

```
./unitsquare.tex:26: LaTeX Error: Command \Box not provided in base LaTeX2e.
```

**Question:** How can I get that symbol with `xelatex` with the fonts in use for that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % avoid \dddot clash
\usepackage{mathtools}  % avoid unicode-math clash
\usepackage{amsthm} % avoid openbox clash

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext}  
  \usepackage{newtxmath}
\fi

\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\unitsq}{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{X}}}

\begin{document}

The unit square is denoted by $\unitsq$.

\end{document}
```

**Related:** [How to type in these "circle" and "square"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278713/how-to-type-in-these-circle-and-square)

Comment: Don't use `fontenc` with XeLaTeX, unless for very special situations. Preparing a document that works in both `pdflatex` and `xelatex` with no change is, unfortunately, just a dream.

Comment: The `\Box` command is provided by the  `latexsym`  package, or `\square`  in the `newtxmath` package

Comment: @Guido: But for `xelatex`, I'm not using `newtxmath`. I don't know how to use `latexsym` with `TeX Gyre Termes Math` under `xelatex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have the impression that you can prepare a document that compiles with both `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. This is not true, I'm afraid.

Anyway, the symbol you're probably looking for is `\lgwhtsquare` corresponding to U+2B1C WHITE LARGE SQUARE, that's unfortunately unavailable with TeX Gyre Termes Math or `\mdlgwhtsquare`, corresponding to U+25A1 WHITE SQUARE.

If you want to scale the symbol to the height of a capital letter, you can use `graphicx` (or `scalerel`, if you prefer).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\newcommand{\unitsq}{\text{\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`X}{$\mdlgwhtsquare$}}}

\begin{document}

The unit square is denoted by $\unitsq$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

An attempt to get a “universal” document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\iftutex
  \newcommand{\unitsq}{\text{\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`X}{$\mdlgwhtsquare$}}}
\else
  \newcommand{\unitsq}{\text{\resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`X}{$\Box$}}}
\fi

\begin{document}

The unit square is denoted by $\unitsq$.

\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex` I get

[image]

Why does LaTeX balk to `\Box`? Because you need `amssymb` for it unless a font package such as `newtxmath` provides by itself the AMS symbols. And no, `unicode-math` doesn't provide `\Box`. Maybe it should…

Comment: Perfect! I forgot about `\mdlgwhtsquare`, which I've used for other purposes with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would rather have a larger square than TeX Gyre Termes Math has, you can borrow one from another math font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  range=\lgwhtsquare,
  Scale=MatchUppercase ]
\newcommand\unitsq{\lgwhtsquare}

\begin{document}

The unit square is denoted by $\unitsq$.

\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Termes + STIX Two sample]

There are numerous white squares in `unicode-math`, including `\lgwhtsquare`, `\mdlgwhtsquare`, `\mdwhtsquare`, `\mdsmwhtsquare` and `\smwhtsquare`.  If none of these are the exact size you want, you can even load any of them with a tweaked `Scale=` option.

Comment: None of these from STIX Two Math seems to both fit with its bottom on the baseline and, when scaled to the size of an uppercase letter, retains sufficient thickness. I'm trying to match, in size and position, a unit circle created with `tikz` by `\newcommand\TikCircle[1][1.125]{\tikz[baseline=-3*#1]{\draw[thick](0,0)circle[radius=#1mm];}} \newcommand{\unitcirc}{\TikCircle}`.

Comment: @murray Okay, that was just an example. However: the same font has `\lgwhtcircle`, `\mdlgwhtcircle`, `\mdwhtcircle`, `\mdsmwhtcircle`, `\smwhtcircle` and `\vysmwhtcircle`, all of which should match if you give them the same scaling. One of those might work for you?